# Инициализация контейнера map С++ Пример на Go

Tags: c++, golang

```
const int OP_CLIENT_LOGIN = 432;
struct OutcomingDate{
    string Time;
};
```

Нужно инициализировать контейнер map, чтобы можно было обратится `cmap[OP_CLIENT_LOGIN]` и получить указатель на OutcomingDate

Как это реализовано на Go:

```
func (p *Packet) GetPck(opcode int) (PacketFactory, error) {
    get, ok := p.pills[opcode] /// 
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("Packet is not found")
    }

    return get, nil
}

type PacketFactory interface {
    Packet(*database.Database) (func(network.Netes), func(*entitie.Player) []int)
}

type Packet struct {
    pills    map[int]PacketFactory
    Player   *entitie.Player
    Database *database.Database
}

type OutcomingDate struct { ///
    Time string
}

func NewPacket(player *entitie.Player, database *database.Database) *Packet {
    return &Packet{
        pills: map[int]PacketFactory{
            support.OP_CLIENT_LOGIN:            &IncomingAuth{},
            support.OP_CLIENT_LOGOUT:           &IncomingExit{},
            support.OP_SERVER_LOGIN:            &OutcomingAuth{}, 
            support.OP_SERVER_CHAPSTR:          &OutcomingDate{}, ///
            support.OP_CLIENT_DELCHA:           &IncomingDeleteCharacter{},
            support.OP_SERVER_DELCHA:           &OutcomingDeleteCharacter{},
            support.OP_CLIENT_UPDATE_PASSWORD2: &IncomingUpdatePassword{},
            support.OP_SERVER_UPDATE_PASSWORD2: &OutcomingUpdatePassword{},
            support.OP_CLIENT_NEWCHA:           &IncomingNewCharacter{},
            support.OP_SERVER_NEWCHA:           &OutcomingNewCharacter{},
            support.OP_CLIENT_BGNPLAY:          &IncomingBeginPlay{},
            support.OP_SERVER_ENTERMAP:         &OutcomingEnterMap{},
            support.OP_CLIENT_KITBAGTEMP_SYNC:  &IncomingKitbagtempSync{},
        },
        Player:   player,
        Database: database,
    }
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предупреждаю, C++ не мой основной язык. Объявления классов:

```
struct MethodReturn {
    std::function<void (void)>             f1;
    std::function<std::vector<int> (void)> f2;
};

class PacketFactory {
    public:
    virtual MethodReturn Packet() = 0;
};

class OutcomingDate : public PacketFactory {
    public:
    std::string time;

    MethodReturn Packet();
};
```

Собственно, функция, возвращающая мап:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<PacketFactory>> f() {
    std::shared_ptr<PacketFactory> od(new OutcomingDate());
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<PacketFactory>> m = {
        {0, od},
        // ...
    };

    return m;
}
```